# UI Bootstrap Typeahead doesn't store selection in ng-model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

Okay so I'm using Ui-Bootstrap typeahead (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead).

I'm using a firebase array for the data.

I've got it to when I start typing it filters the results and I can click one.

When I click it though, it doesn't seem to store the selected value in the model.

What am I doing wrong?

I just want it saved in the ng-model after I select it.

```
<pre>{{newLink | json}}</pre>

<input type="text" ng-model="newLink" placeholder="Search for Pages" uib-typeahead="title as page.title for page in admin.content | filter: {title: $viewValue}" typeahead-show-hint="true" class="form-control"/>
```

My data looks like this (shortened)

```
...
{
   title: 'Home',
   url: 'home',
   published: true,
   html: ''
 }
 ...
```

Here is a short video that shows my problem exactly: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nt2c5wxx9lbuy5v/Problem%201.mov?dl=0

**Update**

If I change `title as page.title for page in admin.content` in the `uib-typeahead` above to `page.title for page in admin.content`. Everything works like expected **EXCEPT** the ng-model only represents the title instead of an array. I really need the firebase uid and the title.

**Update 2**

If I change the `uib-typeahead` again, to `page for page in admin.content` I get what I want in the ng-model except the typeahead options are listed as [object Object].

Comment: I've never used that directive, but are you certain it supports non-string values for `ng-model`?

Comment: Take a look at the docs link listed in the question. It looks like the demos are  doing exactly what I want it to do with my code.

Comment: What about `page.title as page for page in admin.content`?

Comment: @Lex -- That stores the title in the ng-model and still shows [object Object] as the options.

Comment: My bad, I had it backwards. `page as page.title for page in admin.content`. The format is "[value you want to store] as [text you want to display] for [each collection item] in [collection]".

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! Will you put that in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, it's all a matter of building the select directive properly and we were able to figure out that it should be:

```
<input  type="text" 
        ng-model="newLink" 
        placeholder="Search for Pages" 
        uib-typeahead="page as page.title for page in admin.content | filter: {title: $viewValue}" 
        typeahead-show-hint="true" 
        class="form-control"/>
```